# Vue send request until get result from another one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm from Ruby language so sorry for noob question or if my concept is wrong - please tell me.

In my Vue application user should provide some data and asynchronously get the result below the form. The flow is like:

1. user provides input data
2. the app sends POST request (`createProductsRequest`) to Rails backend app
3. Vue get response with `load_id` which represents id of newly created record e.g. 12345 - sample json: `{ load_id: 12345 }`
4. Vue app use `load_id` and send GET request (`fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest`) to Rails backend app endpoint (sample json: `{result: [{test: 'test'}]}`)
5. check if response.result is nil (`{result: nil}`), if yes resent request until it will not be nil
6. display response data

The question is where (and how actually) to put the loop from step 5 that checks if a given response from step 4 does not contain null? Vue should stop sending requests when response is not nil.

Here's what I've produced so far:

`import.js`

```
const createProductsRequest = (self, products) => {
  const jwtToken = self.$store.state.idToken;
  const payload = JSON.stringify({ product_codes: products['product_codes'].split(',') })

  return axios
    .post(`/api/v1/imports/products_batches`, payload,{
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.data)
};

const fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest = (token, id) => {
  return axios
    .get(`/api/v1/imports/products_batches`, {
      params: { id: id },
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data['result']
    })
};
```

`sync_products.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      @click="syncProducts"
    >
      Sync
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    import {
      fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest,
      createProductsRequest
    } from '../../api/imports'
    
    export default {
      name: 'SyncProducts',
      data() {
        return {
          fetchedProductSyncStatus: [],
          load_id: ''
        }
      },
      async mounted() {
        await fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest(this, id)
        this.syncedProductsFetched = true
        this.pageChanged(this.currentPage)
      },
      async mounted() {
        const jwtToken = this.$store.state.idToken;
        fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest(jwtToken).then(data => {
          this.fetchedProductSyncStatus = data
        })
      },
      methods: {
        async syncProducts() {
          let confirmationText = `Do you want to ${this.productsToSyncAmount} sync products?`
    
          if (this.productsToSyncAmount === 0) {
            ModalController.showToast('', 'Type product codes for sync first, please!', 'warning')
          }
          else if (await ModalController.showConfirmation('Confirmation', confirmationText)) {
            try {
              ModalController.showLoader()
              await createProductsRequest(this, this.styleCodes)
              const successMessage = `${this.productsToSyncAmount} products have been queued for sync`
              await ModalController.showToast('', successMessage)
            } catch (data) {
              const errorMessage = `Error occurred during queueing products to sync - `
              ModalController.showToast('', errorMessage + data?.message, 'error')
            } finally {
              this.styleCodes = []
              ModalController.hideLoader()
            }
          }
        },
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If API is returning `null` in the first API call. How it will return the data in another call ?

Comment: I don't think you understand my question or I'm missing something. Response from first API call will always be not `null`

Comment: But why it should be null in any case with the same payload ? If API can return the data with same payload then why there will be a case of null.

Comment: What? these are two separate requests - one with payload and the second is simple GET with `id` as a path parameter.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the GET request, Why it will return sometimes null and sometime data with same `id` that we are passing ?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant question but I'll answer. It will not return id at all. Sometimes it will return null (when backend background job is not finished yet) and sometimes it will return desired response (when backend background job is finished).

Answer (score 0):

To spare your backend i'd probably wait x amount of time (enough for the backend to have created the resource) and then send the get request - instead of potentially spamming it.

With that said i think you want to use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function to call a function that makes the API call. There you can make the call, check if result is nil and then use setTimeout and call the function again if needed. Like so:

```js
async loadId() {
  const data = await makeApiRequest()
  if (!data.result) {
    setTimeout(this.loadId, waitTimeInMillis);
    return;
  }
  //Do what you want if when result isn't null.
}
```

Comment: Good point! but I assume that `loadId` comes from the first export so I need to declare this here - `default {
  name: 'SyncProducts',
  data() {
    return {
      loadId: ''}}` but I want to send this request automatically only if `loadId` is not empty string. How to do so? Sorry if it is basic question but shared code took me a week.

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand correcttly. If you only want to send the request if loadId is not empty string, can't you just make an if request and check like: `if (loadId !== '') { //sendRequest }`

Comment: Like I described in my question. I need to send GET with `id` as a path params (`/products_batches/{id}`) which I will take from the first POST request. So the GET request must be called only when I get this `id` from POST and must be repeated until there is no null in the response.